# tmux: why is my pane name forcibly suffixed with a "Z" char?

Tags: tmux

See my screenshot of tmux, some pane's title always get a suffix "Z" or "-Z", regardless that I have rename them.
[image]

Is there anyone can fix this issue?

My tmux version is 3.2a.
OS is Ubuntu Jammy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tmux manual has a [section about the status line](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#STATUS_LINE).

> the window list shows the index, name and (if any) flag of the windows

The characters `-` and `Z` are flags:

> | Symbol | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | `-` | Marks the last window (previously selected). |
> | `Z` | The window's active pane is zoomed. |

If you don't want these flags, set the [options](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#OPTIONS) `window-status-format` and `window-status-current-format` to values that don't contain the `#{window_flags}` [format escape](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#FORMATS).

```
set-option -g window-status-format "#I:#W"
set-option -g window-status-current-format "#I:#W"
```